# Setting Default Value of DropDownList in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been looking around, and I can't quite find someone attempting to do quite what I am. I have several models that work together on a single page. The models are `employees1`, `phone_manager`, and `phone_types`.

I've managed to get insertion working just fine, but I can't seem to get the edit page to work. I need to take the currently stored `phone_type` which is a foreign key to `phone_type_id` and make it the default item in my combo box.

My model is:

```
[Table("employee.employees")]
public partial class employees1
{

    public employees1()
    {
        employee_email_manager = new List<email_manager>();
        employee_employment_history = new HashSet<employment_history>();
        employee_job_manager = new HashSet<job_manager>();
        employee_phone_manager = new HashSet<phone_manager>();
        this.salaries = new HashSet<salary>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employee ID")]
    public int? assigned_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Web User ID")]
    public int? all_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Birthday")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime birth_day { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name = "Social")]
    public string social { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string address_line_1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Suite/Apt#")]
    public string address_line_2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(11)]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string zip { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime hire_date { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Separation Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? termination_date { get; set; }

    [StringLength(70)]
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Contact Name")]
    public string emergency_contact_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Contact Number")]
    public string emergency_contact_phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string notes { get; set; }

    public virtual all_employees all_employees { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Addresses")]
    public virtual ICollection<email_manager> employee_email_manager { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employment History")]
    public virtual ICollection<employment_history> employee_employment_history { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Position History")]
    public virtual ICollection<job_manager> employee_job_manager { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Phone Numbers")]
    public virtual ICollection<phone_manager> employee_phone_manager { get; set; }

    internal void CreatePhoneNumbers(int count = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            employee_phone_manager.Add(new phone_manager());
        }
    }

    [Table("employee.phone_manager")]
    public partial class phone_manager
    {
        /*public phone_manager()
        {
            phone_types = new HashSet<phone_types>();
        }*/

        [Key]
        public int phone_id { get; set; }

        public int employee_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        [Display(Name="Phone Number")]
        public string phone_number { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5)]
        [Display(Name = "Extension")]
        public string phone_extension { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public int phone_type { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime date_added { get; set; }

        public bool deleted { get; set; }

        public virtual employees1 employees1 { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("phone_type")]
        public virtual phone_types phone_types { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<phone_types> phone_types { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("employee.phone_types")]
    public partial class phone_types
    {
        public phone_types()
        {
            phone_manager = new HashSet<phone_manager>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int phone_type_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string phone_type_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<phone_manager> phone_manager { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.all_id = new SelectList(db.all_employees, "all_id", "all_id");
        var employee = new employees1();
        ViewBag.phone_type = new SelectList(db.phone_types, "phone_type_id", "phone_type_name");
        employee.CreatePhoneNumbers(1);
        return View(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="employee_id,assigned_id,all_id,first_name,last_name,birth_day,gender,social,address_line_1,address_line_2,city,state,zip,hire_date,termination_date,emergency_contact_name,emergency_contact_phone,notes,employee_phone_manager")] employees1 employees1)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (employees1.phone_manager phone in employees1.employee_phone_manager.ToList())
            {
                if (phone.deleted == true)
                {
                    employees1.employee_phone_manager.Remove(phone);
                }
            }
            db.employees1.Add(employees1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var employee = new employees1();
        ViewBag.phone_type = new SelectList(db.phone_types, "phone_type_id", "phone_type_name");
        ViewBag.all = new SelectList(db.all_employees, "all_id", "all_id", employees1.all_id);
        return View(employees1);
    }

    // GET: /Employees/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        employees1 employees1 = db.employees1.Find(id);
        if (employees1 == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var employee = new employees1();
        ViewBag.phone_type = new SelectList(db.phone_types, "phone_type_id", "phone_type_name");
        ViewBag.all_id = new SelectList(db.all_employees, "all_id", "all_id", employees1.all_id);
        return View(employees1);
    }

    // POST: /Employees/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="employee_id,assigned_id,all_id,first_name,last_name,birth_day,gender,social,address_line_1,address_line_2,city,state,zip,hire_date,termination_date,emergency_contact_name,emergency_contact_phone,notes")] employees1 employees1)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(employees1).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var item in employees1.employee_phone_manager)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        var db2 = new LightHouseMain();
        var employee = new employees1();
        ViewBag.phone_type = new SelectList(db.phone_types, "phone_type_id", "phone_type_name");
        ViewBag.all_id = new SelectList(db.all_employees, "all_id", "all_id", employees1.all_id);
        return View(employees1);
    }
```

My View:

```
     @Html.LabelFor(x => x.phone_type)
    @Html.DropDownList("phone_type", string.Empty)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.phone_number)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.phone_number, new { @class = "phone", size = "10" })
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.phone_extension)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.phone_extension, new { size = "4" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.date_added, new { @Value = System.DateTime.Now })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.deleted, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
    @Html.RemoveLink("Remove", "div.phoneNumber", "input.mark-for-delete")
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practise is to not to use ViewBag. Try creating a simple model with properties that your current view needs.

You can also use [SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.#ctor%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) overload of `SelectList` where the object is the selected value. Just use this overload like this:

```
ViewBag.phonetype = new SelectList(db.phone_types, "phone_type_id", "phone_type_name", Model.phone_type );
```

**Note:** I have change ViewBag.phone_type to ViewBag.phonetype.

Comment: Can you you elaborate on this a bit? I tried to do something similar to that, but it appears that my employee model contains nearly everything that I need with the exception of the phone types. The issue is that I'm going to have to repeat this process for about 6 different tables and counting, so anything that simplifies my endeavors is welcome.

Comment: @Jdsfighter db.phone_types is the collection that holds all your phone type data. I saw this in your code in the Create action and thought this is the collection that you want to show up in dropdown.

Comment: @Jdsfighter if you are after ViewBag.phone_type, this is a property that should have the value that user selected before that you want to specify as the default value for your dropdown. You can either use ViewBag or just create a string property in your view-model.

Comment: In the create menu everything works perfectly fine, and I have not complaints, but when I try to use the Edit view, the currently selected phones aren't being passed to the select list. Just as a test I tried to manually set the selected item, but I can't even seem to get that to work.

Comment: I have updated my original post with a diagram of my schema for reference.

Comment: @Jdsfighter that is what I said that you are not passing a collection to the dropdownlist, just try `@Html.DropDownList("phone_type", ViewBag.SelectListOfPhones)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51819/discussion-between-yoda-and-jdsfighter)

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing caused me hours of fun, especially when tackling the [signatures for the DropDownListFor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Anyway, the following will generate a drop down and select the value that is contained within the model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.phone_type, (SelectList)ViewBag.PhoneTypes)
```

If you wish, you can add a third argument, an anonymous object in the same way as the HiddenFor methods do, for styling purposes.

Comment: I might just add that I ended up discarding the ViewBag, as I didn't like the loss of strong typing. Instead, I used various static methods within the business logic layer so that the return type was already correct and the cast was not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That did fix one issue I was having with allowing a null value to be passed, but it doesn't automatically select a default value, it still just selects the first value. As I'm new to Asp.Net I almost feel like I'm looking at gibberish :/

Comment: Ah, I think it's because the ViewBag property has the same name as a property of the model. Try changing the ViewBag property to PhoneTypes, or something similar. I've edited the answer to show this.

Comment: You were actually correct on this one! The major issue was due to a naming conflict! I have no clue why that occurred!

Comment: It's a really sly one, but as it was the cause of a lot of wasted time on my part, it's not one I forget easily!

Comment: From my reading, it appears that all the data that is passed to the view is passed through the viewbag. So even if your aren't explicitly calling ViewBag.Property, it is being passed through it. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do a bit more heavy lifting here.

Loop through the list to build the dropdown and set the selected value when you hit it.

Apologise if I've misread your data structure, but this is the theory:

Controller:

```
var phoneTypeList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var pt in db.phone_types)
{
    phoneTypeList.Add(pt.phone_type_id, phone_type_name);

    if (pt.phone_type_id == employees1.phone_types.phone_type_id)
    {
         selectedValue = pt.phone_type_id;
    }
}
```

Then add phoneTypeList and selectedValue to viewmodel - or ViewBag if you like

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.phone_type, new SelectList(Model.phoneTypeList, "Key", "Value", Model.selectedValue);
```